# No classes when adding JDK9 Platform to Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, platform, java-9

I am having problems adding the new JDK 9 Platform to Netbeans. Here are the steps I followed:

1. I downloaded Java 9 from here: http://jdk.java.net/9/ and ran the installations.
2. In Netbeans I went to Tools, then Java Platforms
3. Clicked on Add Platform
4. Selected Java Standard Edition
5. When asked to choose the platform folder selected "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9"
6. As Platform Source I selected "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\lib\src.zip"
7. And for Platform Javadoc I filled in "http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs.api"

Now I see that if I click on the new JDK 9 platform Sources and Javadoc seem correct, but classes are empty. When I set a project to use the new JDK9 platform I get a lot of exceptions along the lines of "Cannot find package java.lang".

Who can help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been solved. The solution was to install [Netbeans Daily Development Build](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) instead of the Netbeans 8.2 that I use.